# SharedPreferences returning an empty string

Tags: java, android

Why does the toast only show an empty string or whatever I input as the "default" value on the getString line

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.stefan.dijeljenepreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("username", "stefan");

    String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username","");
    Toast.makeText(this,"username:" + username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Missing apply call after the putString

Comment: you didn't use apply() or commit() after edit that's why

Comment: Awesome, that was it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your edits using **apply()** method like this

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("username", "stefan").apply();
```

Comment: @NikocevicStefan glad to help you